# How to implement thousand separator format using TextField in MatBlazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, matblazor, asp.net-blazor

I'm a new beginner at using Blazor ... I'm trying to implement Thousand Separator at TextField using MatBlazor. I've been googling but no luck.

Anybody has an idea/clue how to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here it is: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/o7f5mhga

Comment: @daniherrera Thank you, but it seems a little bit weird ... I put 10,000 ... then I edited to 100 by removing the zeros ... The value still 10,000.

Comment: You should to improve code, use `Try` catch to deal with non-numeric data and so on.

Comment: @daniherrera I think that a lot of boilerplate code that I should have to add just for "Thousand Separator", my requirements are :
1. Prevent non-numeric to be pressed.
2. Support Decimal using format.

I think that I will looking for another Blazor framework ... anyway, thank you for your support.

Comment: I improved it: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/uwhzz21c   see demo: https://twitter.com/ctrl_alt_d/status/1239831245200265217